# Retrieve Data From Facebook to Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio

Currently I am working with an android project where the user should be able to login to facebook with the button - Connect with Facebook, that would redirect to the next Activity with all collected data in one click. i do not know where am i making a mistake. Thanks in advance, The codes are attached below.

**Test** Class is the Facebook SDK initialization class, and the Result Class is **Account**

**Test Class**

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "SocialActivity";
    TextView txt_login_Status;
    LoginButton loginButton;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    URL profile_pic;
    String id;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        //loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Test.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait! Account's being processed!");
                progressDialog.show();
                String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
                Log.i("accessToken",accessToken);
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.i("Test",response.toString());
                            progressDialog.hide();
                            Toast.makeText(Test.this,"Success!! Logged into Account as per given user information. ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            Bundle bFacebookData = getFacebookData(object);
                            String firstname = bFacebookData.getString( "first_name");
                            String lastname = bFacebookData.getString( "last_name");
                            String email = bFacebookData.getString( "email");
                            String profilepic = bFacebookData.getString( "profile_pic");

                            Intent in = new Intent(Test.this, Account.class);
                            in.putExtra("firstname", firstname);
                            in.putExtra("lastname", lastname);
                            in.putExtra("email", email);
                            in.putExtra("Image", profilepic);
                            startActivity(in);

                    }
                });

                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, email");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            }
        });
    }

    private Bundle getFacebookData(JSONObject object) {

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        try{
            id = object.getString("id");
            profile_pic = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?width=100&height=100");
            Log.i("profile_pic", profile_pic +"");
            bundle.putString("profile_pic",profile_pic.toString());
        }catch (JSONException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bundle.putString("idFacebook",id);

        if(object.has("first_name")){
            try{
                bundle.putString("first_name", object.getString("first_name"));
            }catch (JSONException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(object.has("last_name")){
            try{
                bundle.putString("last_name", object.getString("last_name"));
            }catch (JSONException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(object.has("email")){
            try{
                bundle.putString("email", object.getString("email"));
            }catch (JSONException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return bundle;
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

**Account Class**

```
public class Account extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    Button btnSignOut;
    TextView textName, textEmail;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignOut);
        textName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textName);
        textEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textEmail);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);

        String firstname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("first_name");
        String lastname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("last_name");
        String email = getIntent().getExtras().getString("email");
        String profilepic =getIntent().getExtras().getString("profile_pic");

        if (first_name != null && last_name != null && email != null && profile_pic != null) {
                textName.setText(first_name +" "+last_name);
                textEmail.setText(email);
                Glide.with(Account.this).load(profile_pic).into(imageView);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Data isnt Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);


    }
}
```

I have been following a YouTube Tutorial, Link [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R50t9pHtWM0](http://Youtube%20Link)
Facebook Tutorial starts from 45th Minute of the video in a foriegn language.

The message i get on my Emulator is the Toast Message from Account Activity : Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Data isnt Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Facebook Login Works fine, Problem is Data cant be fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is here, I dont really know why though.

but in Account Class, I Gave this

```
if (first_name != null) {
```

Instead of This

```
if (first_name != null && last_name != null && email != null && profile_pic != null) {
```

Comment: The reason i found out was the current Facebook account that i am trying to login was created with the phone number but not with email id. since that account doesn't have an email id it will the email id is anyways null. so if the edited line is something like below example, it would definitely have worked.

`if (first_name != null && last_name != null && profile_pic != null) {`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you

Insted

```
 String firstname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("first_name");
 String lastname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("last_name");
 String email = getIntent().getExtras().getString("email");
 String profilepic =getIntent().getExtras().getString("profile_pic");
```

Use In Account class

```
 String firstname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("firstname");
 String lastname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("lastname");
 String email = getIntent().getExtras().getString("email");
 String profilepic =getIntent().getExtras().getString("Image");
```

Comment: not really, that is what has been used earlier, then i made some changes and tried. no luck.